# Error connecting to Azure SQL server from Azure logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am getting below error - when I try to connect to sql server from logic app using AAD authentication -

Error code: '400', Message: 'Bad Data Source. inner exception: Not a valid data source. clientRequestId:

It was working fine when I started using AAD authentication. I switched to SQL account and it started throwing this error. Now, even if I switch back to AAD it gives me same error.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to sql server from logic app, it will generate a "API Connection" in the same resource group of your logic app, something like below screenshot.

[image]

So please delete this API Connection and then go to your logic app to re-connect to sql server again. It will re-generate another API Connection to connect and connect success.